# Ошибка в MySQL через PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Почему не работает? Как поставить переменную

```
       $result = mysql_query("SELECT `school` . `school`,  `street`
       FROM
      `datacenter`, `school` 
        WHERE
     `datacenter` . `id_school` = `school` . `id_school` 
      AND
   `datacenter` . `name` = '.$name_teacher.'");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     $result = mysql_query('SELECT `school` . `school`,  `street`
FROM
`datacenter`, `school` 
WHERE
`datacenter` . `id_school` = `school` . `id_school` 
AND
`datacenter` . `name` = "'.$name_teacher.'"');
```

Comment: не работает

Comment: Теперь попробуй. =) Шрек слегка ошибся

Comment: о отлично спс

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста. ^.^